# How to view files from SFTP file link in browser

Tags: browser, sftp

I'm using FileZilla to view both Local files (Rebex Tiny Sftp Server) and remote SFTP files.

*My question is:*
As we can view non sftp files like `file:///Z:/AzureConsole/` etc in any browser.

Can we view same way with SFTP URL?

Answer (score 1):

Generally not. The SFTP protocol is significantly different than HTTP (used by browsers) so there is no support for that.

In some cases, you can view the same files using HTTP (if the SFTP files are available in HTTP root of that server), but generally, your best guess is to copy the files locally and open there.

Comment: you mean there no browser support?

Comment: There might be some plugins, but certainly not by default.

Comment: yes I gone through extensions. but I was looking for browser behaviour. thanks for you reply and info :)

Comment: What protocols does a browser typically support? HTTP (therefore Webdav), FTP. I'd really like to create an SSH-based file manager that is viewable in a web browser. Until then, Webdav has to be my technology.